# Is there way to classify the quantifier rank $m$ first order sentence in first order logic

Tags: logic, relations, quantifiers, first-order-logic

In its simplest situation, for example, if the signature contains only a binary relation $\sigma$, so the signature $\tau = \{ \sigma \}$, what are the inequivalent classes of all first order sentences with quantifier rank $m$ over $\tau$?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It is known that for each $m\ge 0$, there are only finite many inequivalent first order sentences with quantifier rank $m$. Is it possible that we can list them, at least recursively, or say more than just "finite many"?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the first-order theory of graphs is undecidable (see for instance [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm40114.pdf)), so given a formula, you cannot even decide if it is equivalent to $true$ on your signature. So it is impossible to enumerate inequivalent formulas of some rank.

Comment: Shouldn't this be semidecidable? First order theories have a sound proof calculus, they just have undecidable statements.

Comment: yes, semidecidable is a particular case of undecidable (same way the halting problem is undecidable).